# Mongo php driver works with errors, where is my fail?

Tags: php, mongodb

**VIDEO IS HERE:** http://youtu.be/ijqde9SLd3s

I have got php code: http://pastebin.com/Bb9SSQpy
I have got this print_r empty result:

> ```
>     MongoCursor Object
> ```
>
> (
>   )

I work with this database: http://pastebin.com/vz7M0KDB
In mongo console all works ok and this command

```
db.unicorns.find({weight:{$lt:400}})
```

give to me this result

> { "_id" : ObjectId("53d191248f800def0598465b"), "name" : "Billy", "gender" : "m", "loves" : [ "banana", "apple" ], "weight" : 120, "vampires" : 14 }

console screenshot here: http://rghost.ru/57170098.view

Where is my problem? Why print_r cursor in php is empty?

Comment: Can you var_dump the $cur var? I suspect it is null but best make sure. Also what PHP Driver version is this?

Comment: var_dump give this empty result: object(MongoCursor)#4 (0) {
} I give my youtube video with this demo from 5 minutes to main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an active connection? By default it connects to your local instance of MongoDB at localhost:27017

See this page for more information about connecting:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php

Comment: With connection all is ok, because, if i change $lt to $ne - all works ok, but $lt or $gt doesn't work. Why?

Comment: You are using a string quotes for the integer value, change the line 16 to: `'$lt' => 400`. Does that fix anything?

Comment: Yes, here is problem, 400 with integer works good. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `print_r(iterator_to_array(MongoCursor Object));` to turn the iterator into an array and print it, or, iterate over it using

```
foreach(MongoCursor Object as $resultObject) { }
```

Comment: this result empty too  - I see white screen only.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of data types, in your PHP you are querying by:

```
   $cur = $col->find(array(
        'weight' => array (
            '$lt' => '400'
        )
   ));
```

But in your database you have:

```
 weight: 600,
```

You must query by the type, take off those string parts and query by int.

Comment: this daabase i take from little mongodb book. May be I change weight for this unicorn earlier. I have got billy with weight=120 in db now